# Android App exits unexpectedly

Tags: android

I am having a weird issue with my app.
Sometimes it spontaneously exits...

Log shows a clean exit, no exceptions, all the callbacks are called in order.
The event log mark the finish reason of the activities as "app_request"
There are no touches or key pressed around the exit
The code does not have any exit feature in it

This does not happen at a specific place, pretty much sporadic

the APK is instrumented when this happens

It is as if the OS decided to close the app cleanly

Have you a clue as to how this happens?

Comment: do you have native code?

Comment: Do you have enough free memory on device?

Comment: seems weird. can you post the main activity, which launches first and forces the app to close unexpectedly?

Comment: Sorry, can't post code... We are using JNI, no native crashes either. Clean exit...

Comment: @Pavel, app that are closed by the system due to memory will not mark app-request at am_finish_activity event, right?

Comment: This issue happened only in one device, or is it happen in other devices and emulator too?